# Adding custom attributes to flot data

Tags: jquery, flot

## The Problem

It would be very convenient when I am passing data into flot if I could pass some supplementary data which I want to access when the `plotclick` event is triggered.

## My Data

Here is some standard data;

```
[{label: 'first', data: 5, color: '#123'},
{ label: 'first', data: 10, color: '#456'}]
```

I want to be able to do something like;

```
[{label: 'first', data: 5, color: '#123', my_custom_attribute: 'some data'},
{ label: 'first', data: 10, color: '#456', my_custom_attribute: 'some more data'}]
```

So that inside of my `plotclick` event I could do;

```
$('chart').bind('plotclick', function(event, pos, item) {
  console.log(item.series.my_custom_attribute) //Or something to that effect
});
```

## What I have tried

I have tried just inserting the above and looking at the returned contents of `item` inside of my `plotclick` event, it doesn't appear to store `my_custom_attribute` anywhere.

I have read through the documentation at https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md and couldn't gleam any relevant information.

I have searched google and here for answers and couldn't find one that suited my needs.

## Update

Thanks to Khawer Zeshan for providing a solution, this still isn't working for me;

Here is the data I am passing in;

```
[{breakdown: "test", color: "#00A4D3", data: 1.5, label: "History"},
 {breakdown: "test", color: "#1464F6", data: 0, label: "Geography"}]
```

But the `breakdown` attribute doesn't appear in the output for `item`.

Everything else about the chart appears to work.

Comment: One possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448320/flot-is-it-possible-to-have-a-third-y-axis-or-hidden-data-set?rq=1

Comment: Could you find any solution for this, @Toby?

Comment: Have you find out something on this issue? I am not getting custom attribute on "plothover" event. Please help me with this

Comment: @SnehalS yes – see Milk Man's accepted answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

If you look up the custom data via the original **`data`**  variable you used when initializing the chart. the data will still be there. For some reason the data cannot be accessed directly through **`item`** ... it seems to get deleted.

```
var data = [
{ label: "Series1",  data: [[1,1]],  myData: "test 1"},
{ label: "Series2",  data: [[1,1]],  myData: "test 2"},
{ label: "Series3",  data: [[1,1]],  myData: "test 3"},
{ label: "Series4",  data: [[1,1]],  myData: "test 4"},
{ label: "Series5",  data: [[1,1]],  myData: "test 5"},
{ label: "Series6",  data: [[1,5]],  myData: "test 6"}
];


$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    }
});



$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
if (item) { 
       console.log(data[item.seriesIndex]);
    }
});
```

**Hope that helps!**

Answer (score 3):

You got that right. You can use custom data parameters to your liking

```
data = [{ data:data1, label:"fixed", lines:{show:true}, my_custom_attribute: 'somedata'}];
```

Than you can get your custom data as follows

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) { 
            alert(item.series.my_custom_attribute);
        }
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KwkqK/30/)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me - do you know if this is something that was introduced in the very latest version of flot? I think we are using a point version behind (I am going to update this now)

Comment: @ATOzTOA Could you find any working solution for this problem?

Comment: After asking you, I overcame this issue by appending the data that I need to pass to 'label' with an underscore like this: 'label: actualLabelData_dataThatIWantToPass. Later on, I split them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

**console.log(data[item.seriesIndex]);**

it works for me...

**For the newer version(0.8) the custom variable directly available in series level like**

**console.log(item.series.my_custom_attribute);**

But for lesser version seriesIndex way should work..

Would like to Thanks @Milk Man