# Where to add and register the custom attributes in flot-pie chart js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flot

Although this question has answer at: [Adding custom attributes to flot data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809126/adding-custom-attributes-to-flot-data)

but I have tried every possible way but my custom attributes are not showing on click event.

So far I tried this:

**html**:

```
<div id="audit_status" class="chart"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
var audit_status = [
    {label: "Pending", data: 2, location_value="Majiwada,Pune"},
    { label: "Ongoing", data: 1 location_value="Mumbai"},
];

var options = {
    series: {
        pie: {
            show: true,
            label: {
                show: true,
                radius: 120,
                formatter: function (label, series) {
                    return '<div style="border:1px solid grey;font-size:8pt;text-align:center;padding:5px;color:white;background-color: #90bdce;">' +
                        label + ' : ' +
                        series.data[0][1] +
                        ' ('+Math.round(series.percent)+' %)</div>';

                },
                background: {
                    opacity: 0.8,
                    color: '#000'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: true
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true,
        clickable: true
    }

};

$("#audit_status").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
    console.log(obj);

    //alert(obj.series.value);
    if (obj) {
        alert(obj.series.location_value);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.plot($("#audit_status"), audit_status, options);
});
```

The problem is: whenever I click the pie segment I want to alert `"location_value"`

but i am getting `[Object Object]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues with the code as it is now. First, the `audit_status` JSON object isn't quite defined right. The `location_value` properties need to use colons, not equal signs:

```
var audit_status = [
    { label: "Pending", data: 2, location_value: "Majiwada,Pune" },
    { label: "Ongoing", data: 1, location_value: "Mumbai" }
];
```

Second, in your `plotclick` function, the extra properties defined in your data object don't make it over to the series object passed into the callback. You need to reference the original data object, using the `obj.seriesIndex` provided to the callback. [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt8v5L0x/3/) provides an example of the code below.

```
var data = [{
    label: "Yes",
    data: 50,
    location_value: 'Majiwada,Pune'
}, {
    label: "No",
    data: 150,
    location_value: 'Mumbai'
}];

// plot initialization code here

$("#pie").bind("plotclick", function(event, pos, obj) {
    if (obj) {
        // use the obj.seriesIndex to grab the original data object,
        // then you can use any property you defined on that object
        alert(data[obj.seriesIndex].location_value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks mechenbier ! you deserve one coffee from my side ! Cheers buddy :)